# Is it possible to install VC toolset version 14.10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Looks like Msft removed VC toolset version 14.10 from their VS Installer:

[image: VS Installer - Individual components]

Is it possible to install VC toolset version 14.10 with VS Installer? (may be using some options)

And if not, does VC toolset version 14.10 available to install? (somehow)

Comment: Could you install it somehow?

Comment: Nope. I did not find any links to obsolete VC toolsets. So, I just use the latest one, keeping in mind that all binaries created by vc140 and vc141 are [binary compatible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/binary-compatibility-and-pain-free-upgrade-why-moving-to-visual-studio-2017-is-almost-too-easy/).

Comment: After some research, I find these howtos to [create offline installer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network.md) and the [list of component ids](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/install/workload-and-component-ids.md), and created an offline installer with the latest toolset, so I can use this toolset in future. If you would like to create offline installer and get stucked somewhere, feel free to ask.